# Why is calc(50% + 0) an error?

Tags: css, calc

When testing out some new layouts, I found myself writing at one point

```
.test1 {width: calc(50% + 0);}
```

and to my surprise, it didn't work.
After verifying that I didn't have a typo anywhere, I was forced to conclude that the browser rejected this as an error. Then I thought maybe it was a flaw in the browser I was testing with, but the other one behaves the same!

So what is it about this expression that is wrong? Where is the error?

```css
p {border:2px solid green}
.test1 {width:calc(50% + 0);}   /* wrong! */
.test2 {width:calc(50%);}       /* OK */
.test3 {width:calc(50% + 0px);} /* also OK */
```

```html
<p class="test1">test 1</p>
<p class="test2">test 2</p>
<p class="test3">test 3</p>
```

(By the way, let me assure you I have no intention of using this in production code; this is just something that came up in testing.)

Comment: Did you try specifying a unit with the zero?

Comment: @Roope yes, see snippet.

Comment: `50% + 0px` should work, doesn't it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is due to [**Type Checking**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-type-checking)

> At + or -, check that both sides have the same type, or that one side is a `<number>` and the other is an `<integer>`. If both sides are
>   the same type, resolve to that type. If one side is a `<number>` and the
>   other is an `<integer>`, resolve to `<number>`.
>
> If an operator does not pass the above checks, the expression is
>   invalid.

Your current code has two values, 50% is a `percentage` and 0 is an `integer`/`number`. It does not confirm to the rules of **Type checking**.

---

**For Poke's comment:**

Reference from [**Computed Value**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-computed-value)

> Where percentages are not resolved at computed-value time, they are
>   not resolved in calc() expressions, e.g. calc(100% - 100% + 1em)
>   resolves to calc(0% + 1em), not to calc(1em). If there are special
>   rules for computing percentages in a value (e.g. the height property),
>   they apply whenever a calc() expression contains percentages.
>
> Note: Thus, the computed value of a calc() expression can be
>   represented as either a number or a ***tuple of a dimension and a
>   percentage.***

So it can be said that `50% + 10px` is an exception to type checking and it is covered in the computed value section of the article.

Comment: In `50% + 0px` both sides don’t have the same type (one is a dimension, the other a percentage), and also neither side is a number nor integer. So I’m not sure how that type checking rule applies here.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that `0` would resolve to a `length`, but apparently not when inside of an expression. Good find!

Comment: @poke Good point there. I read the next paragraph of the article at w3.org It seems to be in sync with your comment.

Answer (score 14):

This is because, the expression (`50% + 0`) consists of two different types.

You might be tempted to think that `50%` is a percentage and `0` is an integer/number, and should not confirm to the rules of type checking. But that is *not correct*. Do not confuse it with `units`. `px, em, %` are all `units` of the `length` type of `dimension-token`. Two different `units` are allowed, but must be of the same `type`. Two different `types` are not allowed.

[W3C says this about types](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-type-checking):

> A math expression has a resolved type, which is one of `<length>,
>   <frequency>, <angle>, <time>, <number>, or <integer>`. The resolved
>   type must be valid for where the expression is placed; otherwise, the
>   expression is invalid. The resolved type of the expression is
>   determined by the types of the values it contains. `<number-token>`s are
>   of type `<number> or <integer>`. A `<dimension-token>`’s type is given by
>   its unit (cm is `<length>`, deg is `<angle>`, etc.).

The left side of your expression: `50%, 50px, or 50em` are **all** `units` of `length` type which are [`<dimension-token>`s](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#typedef-dimension-token), and the right-side of your expression: `0` is an `integer` type which is a [`<number-token>`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#typedef-number-token).

As @Manoj [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32517653/1355315), the `+` or `-` operators specifically restrict the operands to be of same **type** i.e. either `length` or `time` or `number-token`s.

Later in the above ref:

> At `+` or `-`, check that both sides have the same type, or that one side is a `<number>` and the other is an `<integer>`. If both sides are
>   the same type, resolve to that type....

**Summarily**:

```
50% + 0px → Both are of the same type i.e. 'length
50% + 0   → Left is 'length' type and the right is 'integer' type.
```

Comment: Just realized this question can contain multiple answers since my 2nd paragraph for `computed value` exception was also taken into account. But your first paragraph is more convincing and general.

Answer (score 0):

50% (Percentage) and 0 (Int) are 2 different data types much like how an integer (Int) and a string  differ, both need to be of the same type in order to perform the calculation.